# SEVERE: Error in streaming dynamic resource.(apache)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an several image in database saved as String and i want to loop in them and view them dynamically using primefaces.
the output is: sometimes show one image or two or nothing And I used  all scopes (session ,view ,request) the result is the same.

here is the code, i used to convert string to streamed Content :

```
 private StreamedContent getImageFromString(String imageData) throws IOException {
    byte[] imageByte = null;
    BufferedImage imageBuffer = null;
    imageByte = byteToString(imageData);
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
    imageBuffer = ImageIO.read(in);
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(imageBuffer, "png", os);
    return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()), "image/png");

}

public byte[] byteToString(String imageStr) {

    return Base64.decodeBase64(imageStr);
}
```

and the jsf design is :

```
     <ui:repeat  value="#{recent.recentlist}" var="recent" >

            <h:outputText value="#{recent.Id}"/>
            <br/>
            <p:graphicImage value="#{recent.graphicImage}">
                <f:param name="image_id" value="#{recent.Id}"/>
            </p:graphicImage>

            <br/><br/>

            <p:separator/>
        </ui:repeat>
```

the result all the time is ( SEVERE: Error in streaming dynamic resource )

Comment: maybe this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546101/own-resourcehandler-to-stream-images-from-db

Comment: Why do you have images saved as string instead of as blob/bytea?